# single silverlight control in an asp.net mvc website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight

The main website will be MVC but I have a need for one Silverlight control to allow users to draw on images, just basic shapes, lines, squares, triangles etc.

Also might need Silverlight control to potentially allow users to draw and annotate video clips.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer, Yes!

Follow the following link to see a demo app developed by some students in the UK. Integrating something similar in your ASP.NET MVC application can be done by using service calls into Controller methods that return JSON, or strongly typed objects.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SilverPaint

Roberto.-